# How to set an environment variable for just one command in the Fish shell?

Tags: environment-variables, fish

I have an environment variable `GO111MODULE` which is set to `on` in my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
> echo $GO111MODULE
on
```

Following https://fishshell.com/docs/2.2/faq.html#faq-single-env, I would like to set it to `off` for a single command. As a sanity check I tried the `echo` command like so:

```
> env GO111MODULE=off echo $GO111MODULE
on
```

However, I notice that this is printing `on` instead of `off` as I would expect. Can anyone explain why this is not working?

Comment: Try: `env GO111MODULE=off sh -c 'echo $GO111MODULE'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you enter the command

```
env GO111MODULE=off echo $GO111MODULE
```

the variable `$GO111MODULE` is substituted immediately (in the current context) before `env` ever runs or gets a chance to set the variable.  So env just sees `GO111MODULE=off echo on` as its arguments.

In order to see the effect of the environment change, you need to arrange to do the envvar lookup *after* `env` has set it.  So something like:

```
env GO111MODULE=off sh -c 'echo $GO111MODULE'
```

will show the changed variable -- the single `'` around it will prevent the current shell from expanding the var, so `env` will get 4 arguments: `GO111MODULE=off` `sh` `-c` and `echo $GO111MODULE`.  It will then invoke `sh` with two args, which will in turn exapnd the variable and run `echo` with a single `off` arg.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
 set -lx GO111MODULE off; echo $GO111MODULE
 echo $GO111MODULE
```

Sets local environment variable and unfortunately retains it for this session, which might not be what you want.